# Convert PlayStation 4 to USB TV

Tags: usb, hdmi, conversion

Need to convert an HDMI signal from a PlayStation 4 to a USB on TV. Only have USB available on TV.
Do they make a converter to do this.

Comment: The likelihood of your TV displaying video connected to your USB is less than 0.00000001%

Comment: Is it USB C on the TV?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid - if it's not got HDMI the chances of it having USB-C are even slimmer. It's going to be a file reader, plug in a FAT32 stick, nothing more.

Comment: @Tetsujin yes, a fair presumption.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer is no. The USB ports on TVs are not designed for display capabilities, but are rather ports configured to read files from external USB drives.

If your TV does not have an HDMI input you may be able to connect the Playstation in other ways depending on the inputs of your TV, likely through some kind of adapter, but again, the USB port is not an option.